# How to Create Templates for Windows Publisher on a Mac

Tags: mac

I have a client who works in Publisher on a PC however, I work on a Mac and use InDesign. What is the best program for me to set up Templates in InDesign so they can open them up in Publisher on their system?

Jeff

Comment: Time to invest in Office for Windows and run Windows on your Mac.

Comment: I've been down this road many times before.  Publisher's native format is not compatible with anything other than Publisher.  If your client wishes to use his digital assets with other firms or people, he needs to invest in InDesign.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortuneatly my client is prepared to Invest in InDesign. The only other alternative is to run Parallel on my Mac, purely to run Publisher to save files in a comparable format for them to use. 

Anyone had any experience running Parallel on a Mac?

Answer (score 1):

I understand that there may be different ways to achieve the end goal but since no one has come up with a solution at this point, here is what I suggest you try:

There is a neat little application for the Mac called Wine. All in all it allows you to run Windows applications on a mac.
About 7 months ago, I used it to run Publisher on mac without a single hiccup along the way. Your client will save a bit of money with the InDesign app and (depending on the size of your project) perhaps it does the job better than any other third party applications.

Here is a link:
http://smallbusiness.chron.com/open-microsoft-publisher-mac-56433.html

Give it a go and let me know if this answer suits your project.

Answer (score -1):

I've tried Wine and found it really difficult to setup. And when I managed to get it working it often crashed or stopped working suddenly. There are apparently some good alternatives to Microsoft Publisher on Mac though although I haven't tried any of them yet:
https://machow2.com/publisher-for-mac/

Comment: Does the software you recommend allow the creation of templates usuable in Microsoft Publisher (see the question for why this is important)?